# NestedScrollView not showing last cardView with CoordinatorLayout & CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I set up a CoordinatorLayout with a AppBarLayout and a CollapsingToolbarLayout, everything works fine, in this part. Under the AppBarLayout I put a NestedScrollView but when I scroll to the end I can see only half of the last cardview.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/MyAppbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorAccent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="24dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        CARDVIEW x5

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

In my activity :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

What is wrong with my layout ? I looked at some examples but everything look good to me.

Comment: Put fitSystemWindows=true to nestedScrollView

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: I just copy/pasted your code in a blank activity and I can see the bottom of the last card. The CTL doesn't collapse on my end though, does it on yours?

Comment: Yes the CTL collapses (I added the activity part if it helps). If you put a lot of content (lorem ipsum paragraph), can you still see the bottom of the last card ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to get rid of nestedscrollview layout gravity. It worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/appIconIV"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:src="@drawable/special"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="260dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="#b1b1b1" />

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="18dp"
                android:text="Ingredients"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:textSize="23sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#b1b1b1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ingredient_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textSize="15sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:text="Method"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:textSize="23sp" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#b1b1b1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/method_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="12dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp" />
```